# Amazon S3 files distribution across the world

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

If I store my files on Amazon S3 Frankfurt, Germany region, is the file stored only in it's availability zones, or is the file distributed all over the world to other data centres, for example if I live in Europe, I will get this file from Frankfurt, but if I live in Australia, I'll get this file from Sydney Region, or still it will come from Frankfurt if I didn't set up replicas or choose another service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I store my files on Amazon S3 Frankfurt, Germany region, is the
>   file stored only in it's availability zones, or is the file
>   distributed all over the world to other data centres

S3 buckets are not Global, they exist in a specific region and you specify that region when you create a bucket.
So to answer your question, NO, the file will not be distributed all over the world. It will only be stored in different availability zones within the specified region.

> for example if I live in Europe, I will get this file from Frankfurt,
>   but if I live in Australia, I'll get this file from Sydney Region, or
>   still it will come from Frankfurt

You will get the file from Frankfurt region irrespective of where in world you try to load that from because the file was stored in a bucket that belongs to Frankfurt region

Comment: Thanks, this is what exactly is needed, because, in my exact case, files have to be stored somewhere in Europe regardless of the visitor location

Comment: Glad it helped.

Answer (score 1):

> live in Australia, I'll get this file from Sydney Region, or still it will come from Frankfurt

Using pure AWS S3 if you store your files in Frankfurt, they will be loaded from Germany. Indeed it will impose non-negligible latency from Australia.

You can setup S3 cross-region replication or Cloudfront distribution (imho easier to use, as having a single url endpoint) to mitigate the latencty

Comment: Thanks! I also realised that replication requires still more effort, like manually adding the region based on user IP address or something like that, where CloudFront just does it background!

Answer (score 1):

By default, data in S3 is stored within the region that you specify when creating the S3 bucket, and is replicated 'behind the scenes' by AWS to (at least) three separate data centers in that region, for availability. This is not visible in the UI, it's just how it is done by AWS for you to maintain up time.

Thus your data would be in EU Region (one you specified) even if you try to access it from Australia, it will be called from EU Region.

You Can Read [this Documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/storage-classes/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the comment about replication within the region itself. This is also a very cool feature, it is some sort of load balancer principle, I guess

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access your files from anywhere with minimum latency and maximum speed, create a CloudFront distribution for your S3 bucket. So, all your files will be served to your users based on their locations and the AWS edge servers.

[image]

For example, if someone from Australia trying to download your files for the first time, CloudFront download it from your S3 bucket and cache it for the next time on the Australia edge server, for the second time if anyone try to download the same file, CloudFront immediately return the cached version from Australia edge server and never touch your S3 bucket again.

For more information read the following docs on AWS:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/DownloadDistS3AndCustomOrigins.html

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/amazon-s3-amazon-cloudfront-a-match-made-in-the-cloud/

Comment: Thanks for explaining the other alternative! This was not clear before!